# Some variables not saved for a TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a neural network colorization experiment based on this Github project:

[neural network colorization](https://github.com/mohamedkeid/Neural-Image-Colorization/tree/master/src)

In the colorize.py file, I added the following code before I create the saver:

```
ckpt_reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(saved_path)
ckpt_vars = ckpt_reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
print (ckpt_vars)
```

While, when I execute the colorize.py to restore the model and colorize a test image, it print out the stored model as a dictionary:

```
{'generator/conv8e/bias': [512], 'generator/conv8e/batch_normalization/scale': [512], 'generator/conv8e/batch_normalization/offset': [512], 'generator/conv8d/weights': [4, 4, 2, 64], 'generator/conv7e/weights': [4, 4, 512, 512], 'generator/conv7e/batch_normalization/scale': [512], 'generator/conv7e/batch_normalization/offset': [512], 'generator/conv7d/weights': [4, 4, 64, 128], 'generator/conv7d/bias': [64], 'generator/conv7d/batch_normalization/offset': [1], 'generator/conv4e/batch_normalization/scale': [512], 'generator/conv6e/batch_normalization/offset': [512], 'generator/conv6e/bias': [512], 'generator/conv6d/batch_normalization/offset': [1], 'generator/conv4e/bias': [512], 'generator/conv6e/weights': [4, 4, 512, 512], 'generator/conv5e/weights': [4, 4, 512, 512], 'generator/conv5d/weights': [4, 4, 256, 512], 'generator/conv5e/batch_normalization/scale': [512], 'generator/conv5d/batch_normalization/offset': [1], 'generator/conv6d/weights': [4, 4, 128, 256], 'generator/conv4e/weights': [4, 4, 256, 512], 'generator/conv7d/batch_normalization/scale': [1], 'generator/conv4e/batch_normalization/offset': [512], 'generator/conv5d/batch_normalization/scale': [1], 'generator/conv4d/batch_normalization/scale': [1], 'generator/conv3e/weights': [4, 4, 128, 256], 'generator/conv5e/bias': [512], 'generator/conv2e/batch_normalization/scale': [128], 'generator/conv4d/bias': [512], 'generator/conv3d/batch_normalization/offset': [1], 'generator/conv3e/bias': [256], 'generator/conv5d/bias': [256], 'generator/conv3d/weights': [4, 4, 512, 512], 'generator/conv4d/weights': [4, 4, 512, 512], 'generator/conv6d/bias': [128], 'generator/conv3d/batch_normalization/scale': [1], 'generator/conv3e/batch_normalization/offset': [256], 'generator/conv6d/batch_normalization/scale': [1], 'generator/conv5e/batch_normalization/offset': [512], 'generator/conv2e/batch_normalization/offset': [128], 'generator/conv2e/bias': [128], 'generator/conv1d/bias': [512], 'generator/conv2d/weights': [4, 4, 512, 512], 'generator/conv2d/batch_normalization/scale': [1], 'generator/conv3e/batch_normalization/scale': [256], 'generator/conv2e/weights': [4, 4, 64, 128], 'generator/conv7e/bias': [512], 'generator/conv6e/batch_normalization/scale': [512], 'generator/conv1d/batch_normalization/offset': [1], 'generator/conv8d/bias': [2], 'generator/conv1e/weights': [4, 4, 1, 64], 'generator/conv1d/weights': [4, 4, 512, 512], 'generator/conv3d/bias': [512], 'generator/conv1e/bias': [64], 'generator/conv1d/batch_normalization/scale': [1], 'generator/conv8e/weights': [4, 4, 512, 512], 'generator/conv4d/batch_normalization/offset': [1], 'generator/conv2d/bias': [512], 'generator/conv2d/batch_normalization/offset': [1]}
```

but then complaining the following variables are not found in the checkpoint file:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: Key generator/conv4d/batch_normalization/generator/conv4d/batch_normalization/moments/normalize/variance/ExponentialMovingAverage not found in checkpoint
```

and so on.

The stored model and its variables are for the [generator.py.](https://github.com/mohamedkeid/Neural-Image-Colorization/blob/master/src/generator.py)

So my question is how and where the model would store a variable called:

**generator/conv4d/batch_normalization/generator/conv4d/batch_normalization/moments/normalize/variance/ExponentialMovingAverage**

and where might it go wrong since this long-name variable is not properly stored.

Thank you.